# No hot water upstairs after turning off main water to install new sink

Tags: hot-water

Turned off the main water to install a new sink, after we turned it back on there is no hot water in one shower upstairs and very little hot water in one of the other showers.  Checked the hot water heater elements and they good.  Water pressure is good .

Comment: Do you mean that the water pressure to the hot water tank is good but the pressure to the shower is not? Or do you mean that the pressure is good but the water is not hot at the shower head?

Comment: It's entirely possible that some crud in the lines was shaken loose during your work and has now lodged itself somewhere in your supply lines to the showers. Is there a common line between the 2 fixtures with issues?

Comment: @FreeMan  Agreed, with the flow restrictions on faucets for the last few decades, it doesn't take much "crud" to partially or fully plug them up.  Probably at the valve or the shower heads themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I diagnose weak water flow from tub faucet and shower?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/how-do-i-diagnose-weak-water-flow-from-tub-faucet-and-shower)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have some small particles of crud, calcium, whatever sitting in random places in your plumbing system slightly affixed to your pipes.

Water travels over these continuously but there is no real force or pressure on them as the water is always there on both sides.

When you turn the water off and then back on - especially turning it back on full force - these can break off and start "rolling".   They will simply roll to the nearest faucet, shower, or even hot water heater.

If we are working on a house that has a showing soon my guys know to turn on the water slowly.

Answer (score 0):

The repair ; -First shut off the main water again and drain the system water from a low
point in the building
-disassemble the hot water valve side of the shower body- remember during the
entire process to be careful to not get scalded.
-while someone else is opening the main water valve ever so
Slightly let the debris flush out of the valve stem opening.
- reassemble and SLOWLY fill the system back up to leak test it.
- If this is a single handle shower body then the directions are similar but
will be specific to the brand and style.
- Units with anti-scald technology are notoriously prone to clogging from
small debris that gets dislodged from the scenario you described.